# How does `diff` decide whether a difference is change (i.e. replacement) or combination of addition and deletion?

Tags: text-processing, diff

I was wondering how `diff` decides whether a difference is change (i.e. replacement) or combination of addition and deletion?

The best I can find from [diffutils' manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Detailed-Normal.html) is

> ‘fct’
>
> Replace the lines in range f of the first file with lines in range t
>   of the second file. This is like a combined add and delete, but more
>   compact. For example, ‘5,7c8,10’ means change lines 5–7 of file 1 to
>   read as lines 8–10 of file 2; or,if changing file 2 into file 1,
>   change lines 8–10 of file 2 to read as lines 5–7 of file
>   1.

For example, I have two files, each having four lines

```
$ paste f2 f3
0   1
1   2
3   3
5   6
```

and I diff them

```
$ diff f2 f3
1d0
< 0
2a2
> 2
4c4
< 5
---
> 6
```

Why is

```
1d0
< 0
2a2
> 2
```

not

```
1,2c1,2
< 0
< 1
---
> 1
> 2
```

instead?

The alternative I gave and the `diff` output both have `3` as the common line, but my alternative treats the different lines before the common line as `c` i.e. replacement, while the `diff` output treats them as a combination of deletion and addition.

Comment: If you read the manual, it says [`diff` tries to minimize the total hunk size by finding large sequences of common lines interspersed with small hunks of differing lines...](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Hunks) there are even examples etc...

Comment: Thanks. Can you be more specific when it comes to my questions?

Comment: No. I think the manual is very clear, just read the _hunks_ subsection that I linked to...

Comment: I have. But I can't relate it here. I was wondering whether I am missing something, or  you actually miss my question?

Comment: Well, I _cannot_ understand most of your questions but this one is pretty clear... And so is the answer in the manual: [_In general, there are many ways to match up lines between two given files._](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Hunks)

Comment: Your link shows different possibilities of common lines. If you have ever read my example, the common lines in the diff output and my alternative are both `3`. So your link is unrelated to my question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The LCS between the two files is `1 3`, instead of `3`. So there are three hunks, instead of two hunks between the two files.